# Using Angular require on input to enable signup: require input's/ validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two input's(checkboxes). One is for a student and the other is for consultant. I want to require at least one or the other input checkboxes. I got them to switch if one is clicked. I just can't figure out how to get it to run inline with the rest of the form validation.

Student:

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="userTypeClass" checked="checked" id="studentCheckbox" name="studentCheckbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-model="user.userType" ng-change="inputCheck(user)"/>
```

Consultant:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="userTypeClass" id="consultantCheckBox" name="consultantCheckBox" ng-true-value="2" ng-model="user.userType" ng-change="inputCheck(user)"/>
```

Signup Button:

```
<button class="col button-green" ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid && !flag" ng-click="submit(user)">Continue</button>
```

JS Controller function:

```
                $scope.inputCheck = function(user) {
        var flag = false;
        if (user.userType == false) {
            flag = true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }
        console.log(flag);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better answer but here's an idea-

```
<input type="checkbox" class="userTypeClass" checked="checked" id="studentCheckbox" name="studentCheckbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-model="user.userType" ng-change="inputCheck(user)"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="userTypeClass" id="consultantCheckBox" name="consultantCheckBox" ng-true-value="2" ng-model="user.userType" ng-change="inputCheck(user)"/>

<input type="hidden" required ng-model="user.userType"/>
```

With the hidden input you're insuring at least one is checked. I don't know the purpose of your inputCheck method but here is a way it could be cleaned up-

```
$scope.inputCheck = function(user) {
  var flag = user.userType === false;
  console.log(flag);
};

// or if you dont need to store the flag:

$scope.inputCheck = function(user) {
  console.log(user.userType === false);
};
```

Edit:

Hmm I didn't know false wouldn't work. You could try a hidden checkbox-
(untested, not sure if this will work)

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-hide="true" required ng-model="user.userType"/>
```

Or you can unset the value in `inputCheck` but it's a bit clunky.

```
$scope.inputCheck = function(user) {
  if(user.userType === false) {
    user.userType = undefined;
  }
};
```

Comment: this is a great answer, and it works. The form validate's until one of them is chosen. But if they un-click and now userType is now false form stays valid. Do you have any idea's?

Comment: Tried the update, but the state doesnt change for the checkbox. remains untouched/invalid.

Comment: Ah I see- just go with the function way then.

Comment: Perfect!!!!! Thank you so much and on a saturday evening, appreciate the help very much.

Comment: I'm a strange person. No problem :)